# Board for lectures, with arrows, highlights, not checking rules

Tags: software

Is there good free software for creating video lessons, that allows you to make board as big as desired, highlight squares, show arrows and not checking rules, allowing to move pieces in any way, playing without king etc? I mean just board software, not software for capturing video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a setup board function is programs like scid and chessbase.  These boards aren't full screen. In setup mode, they don't allow for arrows and highlights.
It might be better to just program the software yourself.  This would make all the features just as you like.

http://scid.sourceforge.net/

http://en.chessbase.com/post/new-and-blindingly-fast-chebase-light-2009

Chessity.com has a new e-tool for teachers.
[image]
Allows illegal moves, coins and flags on any square, and four colored arrows and squares.  Large enough for students in back to see clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://www.apronus.com/chess/diagram/editor/ will satisfy your needs. If not, then please let me know because I am the author of this free tool and I am still working on improving it.

Perhaps http://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/ in the setup mode will be also useful. The problem with these tools is that they are very powerful but not easy to operate without instruction. So do not get discouraged just ask for help.

Comment: I know this tool a little, used sometimes, but for different purposes. When I will be at home, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I tried, pieces movement in pgnviewer without checking rules is good, but I see no way how can I make board bigger there and how to use arrows and square highlights there. In the editor clicking on a square runs a listbox for piece choice or it is checking rules when moving, this is not for videos. Is there some way how to combine functionalities from both? Also I didn't succeed in adding arrow in any of boards.

Comment: Arrows can be added at http://www.apronus.com/chess/diagram/editor/ by choosing the "diagram image editor" radio button. The "position setup" radio button indeed has an awkward way of setting up the position from a listbox. But this has the full functionality of setting a position, adding arrows and square highlights, modifying images, and downloading an image file.

Comment: The board editor at http://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/ is a completely different interface. In the "position setup" mode you can tick the checkbox "animation sequence" to generate an animated image showing any conceivable scenario on the chessboard.

Comment: These two interfaces can be used together but it is not really user friendly although it can be done. One way to communicate between them is to generate FEN in one of them and paste into the other. To go from pgnviewer to diagram/editor you can also click the button "Puzzle Editor" and then the Diagram button at the top and then "static diagram editor". Once again: all of this is powerful but not easy to use without instruction.